# Can't merge an LVM snapshot into it's origin

Tags: linux, lvm

I recently had a problem with an LVM volume because it's ran out of CoW space. I added more space to the volume and restarted it, now it shows CoW is only 66% full. It seems LVM created a snapshot with data it couldn't write when CoW was full, but I don't want to use snapshots, so I tried to merge it back to the origin:

```
# lvconvert --merge shared/spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1
 Internal error: #internal LVs (5) != #LVs (3) + #snapshots (1) + #internal LVs (2) in VG shared
 Unable to merge LV "spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1" into its origin.
```

My logical volumes currently looks like this:

```
# lvscan -a
ACTIVE            '/dev/shared/kkm03.ofd.com.sel-disk1' [80.00 GiB]   inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/shared/mirror01.inf.com.sel-disk1' [150.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/shared/spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1' [30.10 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE   Original '/dev/shared/spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1_vorigin' [100.00 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/system/root' [7.45 GiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/system/tmp' [976.00 MiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/system/swap' [488.00 MiB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/system/var' [7.88 GiB] inherit
```

I was thinking about just removing the snapshot, but I dont see /dev/shared/spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1_vorigin in the filesystem, so I'm not sure if I'll be able to recover it.

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LVM terms, the `merge` means you want to **revert** back to your previous logical volume state, losing all changes done from when the snapshot was taken.

From what I understand, it is not what you want. Rather, you want to delete the old snapshot to recover space. This means you should issue a `lvremove shared --name spark03.ofd.com.sel-disk1`

Obviously, **triple-check each command** before to issue the wrong one! And take regular backups...